# How to save and add data in sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on a project in which I perform mathematical operations and then output the results and I added these results in sharedpreferences and this happens when I press button add that saves the results of this page and clears the entries to make another calculation .. I want to save the second results and when you click on the All Results button, the second results are saved in sharedpreferences and the first results are add with the second results

```
case R.id.btn_add:
              mUserData.saveData1(aPc, aRc);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name'1' is Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            clearEditTxt();


        mUserData.saveData2(aPc, aRc);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name'2' is Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        clearEditTxt();
    break;

case R.id.btn_all_result:
    if (dataIsEmpty()) {
        allaPc = Double.parseDouble(mUserData.getUserData1().get(UserData.Key_PConcrete))
                + Double.parseDouble(mUserData.getUserData2().get(UserData.Key_PConcrete2)); 

        allaRc = Double.parseDouble(mUserData.getUserData1().get(UserData.Key_RConcrete))
                + Double.parseDouble(mUserData.getUserData2().get(UserData.Key_RConcrete2));
  }
            break;

    }
}

private boolean dataIsEmpty() {
    if (mUserData.getUserData1().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Saved '1' is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    } else if (mUserData.getUserData2().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Saved '2' is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

private void clearEditTxt() {
    mLpc.setText("");
mBpc.setText("");
}
```

The problem is that the results of the second calculation are added and combined twice

```
public class UserData {

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    Context mContext;

    private static final String File_Name = “name_app”;
    public static final String Key_PConcrete = "user_PConcrete";
    public static final String Key_RConcrete = "user_RConcrete";

public static final String Key_PConcrete2 = "user_PConcrete";
public static final String Key_RConcrete2 = "user_RConcrete";

public UserData(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mSharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(File_Name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
}

public void saveData1(double PConcrete, double RConcrete) {
    mEditor.putString(Key_PConcrete, String.valueOf(PConcrete));
    mEditor.putString(Key_RConcrete, String.valueOf(RConcrete));
mEditor.apply();
}

public HashMap<String, String> getUserData1() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put(Key_PConcrete, mSharedPreferences.getString(Key_PConcrete, null));
    user.put(Key_RConcrete, mSharedPreferences.getString(Key_RConcrete, null));
return user;
}
public void saveData2(double PConcrete, double RConcrete) {
    mEditor.putString(Key_PConcrete2, String.valueOf(PConcrete));
    mEditor.putString(Key_RConcrete2, String.valueOf(RConcrete));
mEditor.apply();



}

public HashMap<String, String> getUserData2() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put(Key_PConcrete2, mSharedPreferences.getString(Key_PConcrete2, null));
    user.put(Key_RConcrete2, mSharedPreferences.getString(Key_RConcrete2, null));

 return user;
}
```

Comment: pure guessing: `Key_PConcrete2 = "user_PConcrete"` should be `Key_PConcrete2 = "user_PConcrete2"` to prevent name clashing....

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work too

Comment: and you did the same for `Key_RConcrete2` as well?